# Grunt does not compile font-awesome.LESS or CSS

Tags: css, fonts, less, gruntjs, font-awesome

The already answered questions on this issue didn't solve my problem.

When I pull in the [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) library with [Bower](http://bower.io/) and integrate the library directly in `index.html` or alternatively use the hosted version like in the following, the icons are displaying fine:

```
<link href="bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

or

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, no icons are displayed when I am compiling font-awesome.less or font-awesome.css with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (Please see the picture: The Bootstrap LESS which I import in base.less works fine!):

**frontend.less:**

```
@import "base.less";
@import "/bower_components/fontawesome/less/font-awesome.less";

//@import (less)"//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";
```

**Gruntfile.js (excerpt):**

```
less: {
        development: {
            options: {
              compress: true,  // Minification
            },
            files: {
              // Compile frontend.less into frontend.css
              "./public/assets/css/frontend.min.css":"./app/assets/less/frontend.less",
              // Compile backend.less into backend.css
              "./public/assets/css/backend.min.css":"./app/assets/less/backend.less",
            }
        }
    },
```

I would appreciate your advise how to import / compile `font-awesome.less` correctly with Grunt or if this is a Font Awesome bug.

[image]

Comment: Most likely the paths to the actuall font files are incorrect in the compiled CSS. See https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/pull/3138 (though the solution they used there is somewhat flawed, the correct solution is to use [`--relative-urls`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-relative-urls)/[relativeUrls](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less#relativeurls) option or simply set the `@fa-font-path` variable in the file you import the `font-awesome.less` from).

Comment: @seven-phases-max You are right: the path for both Font Awesome and Glyphicons are incorrect. Chrome Console returns a 404 Error for the fonts. As you suggested I added `@fa-font-path: "bower_components/font-awesome/fonts";` and `@icon-font-path: "bower_components/bootstrap/fonts";` to frontend.less, but it keeps pointing to `http://localhost/testing/public/assets/css/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3` in the public folder. The fonts are actually in the bower_components folder in root. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure you define `@icon-font-path` *after* `@import ".../font-awesome.less";` (Less uses "last definition wins" principle).

Comment: I did and it is still not working. I can fix the Glyphicons by using an absolute path like `@icon-font-path: "http://localhost/testing/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/";`, but that is not really an ideal solution. Font Awesome keeps adding the version number to the end of the link, which messes up the path... `path.less` does not seem to be correctly written.

Answer (score 1):

According your Grundfile.js you will create the `./public/assets/css/frontend.min.css` file for your compiled css. You should set @fa-font-path relative to that file. Because of `"http://localhost/testing/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/"` works in your situation also `@icon-font-path: "testing/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/"`.

In you frontend.less:

```
@import "base.less";
@import "/bower_components/fontawesome/less/font-awesome.less";
@icon-font-path: "testing/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/";
```

Alternatively copy the font files from `/bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/` to `/public/assets/fonts` and set @icon-font-path: "../fonts" (the default already defined in "/bower_components/fontawesome/less/variables.less).

Notice that v4.2 of Font Awesome also allows you to set:

```
@fa-font-path:        "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/fonts"; // for referencing Bootstrap CDN font files directly
```